# Whitening data before regression, should I whiten the response variable too?

Tags: regression, pca, confounding, eigenvalues

I have some data X where the samples are not independent (they're correlated with each other), and I'm trying to do a regression of some continuous variable y on X. This sample correlation could confound my analysis.

Hence, I thought of using ZCA whitening to correct for this inter-sample covariance in X
$$
X_{\mbox{zca}} = U D^{-1} U^T X,
$$
based on SVD
$$
X=UDV^T.
$$

In addition to correcting the input data, should I also correct the response variable y (using the same singular values/vectors used to transform X) 
$$
y_{\mbox{zca}}=UD^{-1}U^Ty
$$
and then do the regression of y on X?

Comment: If your $y$ is one-dimensional, then what would $U^\top y$ even mean? $U^\top$ rotates features of $X$, it simply cannot be applied to $y$. Your last formula does not make sense.

Comment: Why not? $U D^{-1} U^T$ is of dimension $n \times n$ and $y$ is $n \times 1$, so $U D^{-1} U^T y$ is also $n \times 1$.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your reply. It looks like I might have misunderstood your original question. I thought you whiten the features of X (so that transformed features are uncorrelated), but you whiten *the samples*, don't you? In this case my comment above does not apply; but I have never encountered such an approach before.

Comment: Yes, whiten the samples because they are correlated with each other, kinda similar to what a linear mixed model does by assuming a non-diagonal covariance of the errors. This is for genome-wide association studies, where accounting for relatedness is important because it implies population stratification and/or cryptic relatedness which can confound analyses.

Comment: If you "sample-whiten" the X, you *have to* apply the same transformation to Y, otherwise the regression won't make sense because rows of X (samples) will not correspond to rows of Y anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not knowledgeable on the method you are proposing but another possible (and probably simpler) solution is to use Generalized Least Squares.  Generalized Least Squares can be used when the residuals exhibit non-constant variance and/or are correlated.

In R one can use the gls function and specify a particular correlation structure among the residuals.  More info here: http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~iruczins/teaching/jf/ch5.pdf

Comment: It seems the two methods are closely related, both are trying to find the inverse of the covariance in order to make the covariance diagonal. In GLS you modify the response as well as the predictor, so it might be a good idea to do so here as well.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the whitening process is only implemented on the independent variable (X) but not dependent variable (Y). The aim is just to remove the correlations between the data in X and equalize the variances.